# Building an object factory that supports inheritance

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to create an object factory weapon class, that can instanciate an infinite amount of the projectile class I have assigned to it. The weapon class and the projectile class are used as "abstract" classes (I know Delphi 7 doesn´t support abstract classes).

Now I donßt know how to implement the Weapon.shoot() that instanciates the projectileType properly (The SimpleWeapon class uses SimpleProjectile as the projectileType)

```
procedure Weapon.shoot();
var g : Projectile;
begin
        // instanciate ammo type
        g := projectileType.create();
        g.init();
end;
```

First, projectileType.create() returns a TObject which I can´t assign directly to a Projectile variable, and casting the TObject by projectileType(g) also doesn´t work.

Second, how can I achieve that g will be casted into the projectileType, so that I can use the init() method of that specific class and not it´s parent (Projectile) ?

[image: UML diagram]

Comment: Let it be Jagged Alliance 3, please, dear Santa, please...

Answer (score 3):

Declare a class type `SimpleProjectileClass = class of SimpleProjectile`. Then make projectType return that type: `projectType: SimpleProjectileClass`.

Comment: But wouldn´t that be hardcoding the projectily type to the weapon type? I want it so that it´s a variable so for example a weapon can switch between different projectile types

Comment: Not as long all projectiles inherit from SimpleProjectile.

Answer (score 2):

The weapon does not need to know, what kind of projectile it could fire. It only should know, to fire/shoot.

So implementing a Weapon Strategy would be the best advice

```
type
  TWeapon = class;

  IWeaponStrategy = interface
    ['{B47CD780-906D-4515-BDA6-1EC8118BC29E}']
    procedure Shoot( AWeapon : TWeapon );
  end;

  TWeapon = class
  private
    FStrategy : IWeaponStrategy;
  public
    procedure Shoot;

    procedure SetStrategy( AStrategy : IWeaponStrategy );
  end;

implementation

{ TWeapon }

procedure TWeapon.SetStrategy( AStrategy : IWeaponStrategy );
begin
  FStrategy := AStrategy;
end;

procedure TWeapon.Shoot;
begin
  FStrategy.Shoot( Self );
end;
```

To get a weapon firing bullets build a WeaponBulletStrategy

```
type
  TWeaponBulletStrategy = class( TInterfacedObject, IWeaponStrategy )
  protected
    procedure Shoot( AWeapon : TWeapon );
  end;

implementation

procedure TWeaponBulletStrategy.Shoot( Aweapon : TWeapon );
begin
  // Build the Bullet Instance and initialize
end;
```

Now you can easily change the weapon shoot behavior or implement new projectile classes without changing the weapon class.

Comment: Well, actually firearm barrel do know.

Comment: Do you really think barrel and bullet are talking to each other? The barrel does not even now, a bullet is loaded. Only when both are in right place there will be interaction. And it is up to you, what kind of bullet you load, the barrel does not care.

Comment: Shooting a steel BB or flechette will damage your rifled barrel. Shooting a proper bullet from smooth-bore barrel will give you a outstanding spread. Yes, real ballistics depends of the projectile type and barrel type.

Comment: I do agree, but you did not illustrate the strategy itself. Do not take this as a critics to your approach (it is even better than mine), but I'd like to see how you'd implement it.

Answer (score 2):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

  TBaseProjectile=Class
     Procedure Init;
  End;

  TProjectile_1=Class(TBaseProjectile)
  End;

  TProjectile_2=Class(TBaseProjectile)
  End;

  TBaseProjectile_Class=Class of TBaseProjectile;
  TProjectile_1Class=Class of TProjectile_1;
  TProjectile_2Class=Class of TProjectile_2;

  TBaseWappon=Class
    FClassRef:TBaseProjectile_Class;
    protected
    public
    Constructor Create(ProjektileClass:TBaseProjectile_Class);virtual;
    Procedure Shoot;
  End;

  TWappon_1=Class(TBaseWappon)
    public
  End;

  TWappon_2=Class(TBaseWappon)
    public
  End;


  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TBaseProjectile.Init;
begin
    Showmessage(Classname);
end;



{ TBaseWappon }

constructor TBaseWappon.Create(ProjektileClass:TBaseProjectile_Class);
begin
   FClassRef:=ProjektileClass;
end;

procedure TBaseWappon.Shoot;
begin
  With FClassRef.Create do
    begin
    init;
    Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  With TWappon_1.create(TProjectile_1) do
    begin
      Shoot;
      Free;
    end;
  With TWappon_2.create(TProjectile_2) do
    begin
      Shoot;
      Free;
    end;

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my view insight the problem:

```
type
  TProjectile = class
  protected
    function GetDamage: Integer; virtual; abstract;
    function GetPenetration: Double; virtual; abstract;
  public
    procedure DoExtenalBallistics(WindSpeed, WindDirection: Real); virtual;
    procedure DoInternalBallistics(Acceleration: Real); virtual;
    procedure DoTerminalBallistics(TargetArmor: Real); virtual;
    property Damage: Integer read GetDamage;
    /// <summary>
    /// Sorry, can not resist ;-)
    /// </summary>
    property Penetration: Double read GetPenetration;
  end;

procedure TProjectile.DoExtenalBallistics(WindSpeed, WindDirection: Real);
begin
  // TODO : do parabolic travel within the gravity pull of Earth, affected by wind
end;

procedure TProjectile.DoInternalBallistics(Acceleration: Real);
begin
  // TODO : do gain kinetic energy in the acceleration chamber
end;

procedure TProjectile.DoTerminalBallistics(TargetArmor: Real);
begin
  // TODO : TargetHitPoitns - (Damage / (TargetArmor - Penetration)) or something
end;

type
  TProjectileType = class of TProjectile;

  TFirearm = class
  protected
    function GetSupportedProjectile: TProjectileType; virtual; abstract;
  public
    function CanShoot(Projectile: TProjectile): Boolean; virtual;
    procedure Shoot;
    property SupportedProjectile: TProjectileType read GetSupportedProjectile;
  end;

function TFirearm.CanShoot(Projectile: TProjectile): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Projectile is SupportedProjectile;
end;

procedure TFirearm.Shoot;
var
  Projectile: TProjectile;
begin
  Projectile := SupportedProjectile.Create;
  Projectile.DoInternalBallistics(CardridgePowder);
  Projectile.DoExtenalBallistics(Theatre.Wind.Speed, Theatre.Wind.Direction);
  Projectile.DoTerminalBallistics(Targer.Armors);
  { ... }
  { ofc is CanShoot returns false, then http://i192.photobucket.com/albums/z96/M4builder/destructivetestedbarrrels01copy.jpg and Firearm.Owner.Fingers - 5 }
end;

type
  TSmoothBoreProjectile = class(TProjectile)
  end;

  TBuckshot = class(TSmoothBoreProjectile)
  end;

  Flechette = class(TSmoothBoreProjectile)
  end;

  TShotgun = class(TFirearm)
  protected
    function GetSupportedProjectile: TProjectileType; override;
  end;

function TShotgun.GetSupportedProjectile: TProjectileType;
begin
  Result := TSmoothBoreProjectile;
end;
```

I've ommitted several required overrides for the sake of brevity (model is much more bigger that original class diagram) and replaced your proposed `Init` methods with pseudos related to what actual projectile should do.